# Is it possible to create a new instance of a HTMLSlotElement with some assigned nodes?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, custom-element

I'm trying to unit test a function that takes a `HTMLSlotElement` as one of its arguments and then reads its assigned nodes. Is it possible to create a new instance of a `HTMLSlotElement` with some assigned nodes programmatically so I can pass it to the function?

Comment: It's just an object with some defined properties and methods, hence...

Comment: The assignedNodes property is read only

Comment: Just use a regular object and add the relevant properties. Unless the function tests for the actual (proto)type this should work: `const fakeObject = { nodeType: 1, nodeName: "DIV", children: [ ... ], ...}`

Comment: I did think of that but my tests are written in Typescript.

Answer (score 2):

In the end I did it by overriding the assignedNodes function

```
    const heading = document.createElement('h1');
    heading.innerText = 'test heading';
    Object.defineProperty(titleSlot, 'assignedNodes', {
      value() {
        return [heading];
      },
      writable: false
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The HTMLSlotElement is an interface, you can`t create an instance.

But you can use this interface (it`s like a static class in C#) like this:

```
> HTMLSlotElement.ELEMENT_NODE
> HTMLSlotElement.other Methods/properties
```

Comment: I would be creating the element with `document.createElement('slot')`

Comment: Just do it. var x = document.createElement('slot');

Comment: I also want to assign some nodes

Comment: Like this?

    var node = document.createElement('slot');
    document.getElementById("myId").appendChild(node);

Comment: No, the HTMLSlotElement is used within templates for projected content. Nodes are assigned to them using the `slot` attribute on the element you want to assign. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSlotElement